# EmberJS model from route returns undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, npm, ember.js, ember-data

Can some one help me on the below doubt?

I am using EmberJS 3.4 version and I have a route which looks like

```
export default Route.extend({
model(){
    const items = [{price: 10}, {price: 15}]
    return items
 },
});
```

and a controller which returns undefined for model

```
export default Controller.extend({

    init(){
        console.log(this.model); //returns undefined
        console.log(this); //has the model object as a property
    },
  })
```

see this image which contains output:
[image: see this image which contains output]

For some reason, this.model returns undefined but when I log "this", it has the model object as the property listed.

My question is, when I access model within a computed property why the property isn't undefined ?

export default Controller.extend({

```
subtotal: computed('this.model', function(){
     return  this.model.reduce((acc, item) => {
         return acc + item.price
     },0) // return 25
    }),
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are singletons, so you can't access the model in `init`.

> when I access model within a computed property why the property isn't undefined ?

Accessing in computed properties (and in more modern ember, native getters) is the only way to have a reactive access to the `model` property. This "reactiveness" keeps all your data in sync -- and in ember 3.4, computeds' callbacks are not invoked until the dependencies are also resolved).

More information

- about controllers: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/controllers/#toc_where-and-when-to-use-controllers (current docs (4.3 at the time of writing))
- about computed properties: https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.4.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-properties-only-recompute-when-they-are-consumed (docs from 3.4)

> For some reason, this.model returns undefined but when I log "this", it has the model object as the property listed.

this happens because you log an `object`, and objects in the console are not *copied* to the console, the reference is rendered, so if you're not fast enough, the data will all be resolved / settled by the time you view it.